# VB.NET read .XML file and write into DataGridView

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, datagridview

I'm trying to read an .XML file online and then write it into the DataGridView.
Downloading the file works. But how can i put the downloaded data to my DataGridView.

VB.NET Code:

```
Dim xmlfile As String
        Dim WebC As New System.Net.WebClient
        Dim datas As New DataSet


        Try
            xmlfile = WebC.DownloadString("https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml")
            datas.ReadXml(xmlfile)
            DataGridView1.DataSource = datas.Tables("cube")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

and this is the .XML File:
https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml

thanks for every help..

I expect the .xml file to be displayed in the DataGridView. Because I want to display all currency rates.

Answer (score 1):

Put data into a datatable than make the datagridview1.DataSource = dt;

vb.net

```
Imports System
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Imports System.Data

Module Program
    Const URL As String = "https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml"
    Sub Main(args As String())
        Dim dt As New DataTable

        dt.Columns.Add("currenct", GetType(String))
        dt.Columns.Add("rate", GetType(Decimal))
        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(URL)
        Dim ns As XNamespace = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace()
        For Each cube As XElement In doc.Descendants(ns + "Cube").Where(Function(x) Not x.Attribute("currency") Is Nothing)

            Dim currency As String = CType(cube.Attribute("currency"), String)
            Dim rate As Decimal = CType(cube.Attribute("rate"), Decimal)
            dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {currency, rate})

        Next
    End Sub
End Module
```

c# solution

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        const string URL = "https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("currenct", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("rate", typeof(decimal));
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(URL);
            XNamespace ns = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
            foreach(XElement cube in doc.Descendants(ns + "Cube").Where(x => x.Attribute("currency") != null))
            {
                string currency = (string)cube.Attribute("currency");
                decimal rate = (decimal)cube.Attribute("rate");
                dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { currency, rate });
                
            }
        }
 
    }
}
```